# Xiaomi source code

Tags: xiaomi, open-source

Does anyone know where I can find the source code of Xiaomi. I don't mean only the kernel code like this [here](https://github.com/MiCode/Xiaomi_Kernel_OpenSource/tree/whyred-n-oss), but the whole code for their OS just like I can get it from [here](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/) for Android in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't find it

OEMs are *forced* to reveal kernel code because they use Linux kernel code suitably modified (see [licenses](https://source.android.com/setup/start/licenses))
. Rest is proprietary. They are not obliged to share and on the contrary, it is guarded so that competitors do not take advantage of their features